# PyGTK: Stop TextView from updating until manually requested

Tags: python, pygtk

I have an application that parses ~1GB of text data, so in my main worker loop, I periodically do the following to keep the GUI up to date:

```
while gtk.events_pending(): gtk.main_iteration()
```

This works great and the data gets processed quit quickly. The problem is when I add a TextView for debug. I only add small amount of tagged data at a time, but tons of it, which apparently creates a lot of pending events and causes the program to go about 100x slower.

I want a way to control when the TextView sends pending events (for example, update every 100 inserts instead of every insert) so `gtk.main_iteration` is really working off events for the rest of the GUI. Is something like this possible?

Comment: you could try to use two text buffers and attach only one of them to the textview. Insert data into the unattached buffer and swap buffers (one is displayed, another accepts new data) every 100 inserts or so. And/Or process the data in a background thread leaving the main thread for gtk main. Multiple threads might slow down the overall process depending on how much processing you do compared to IO or whether you use modules that can release GIL (for multiple CPUs) such as `regex`, `lxml`.

Comment: That is a good idea. I'll give that a shot on Monday and post the results. Thanks!

Comment: Here's [an example where an output from an external subprocess is read in a background thread and shown in a gtk label](https://gist.github.com/zed/8a255e81eb87431c0e63)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Using 2 buffers worked. Although, I had to set the buffer at the very end, it allowed the application to run at normal speed. If you want to post that comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: you could [post your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) if you've tested it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian alright, just thought you'd want credit since it is your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try using python generators like this:

```
def add_data(file, limit=1000):
    with open(file, "r") as textfile:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(textfile):
            text_buffer.insert_at_cursor(line)
            if line_num >= limit and line_num % limit == 0:
                textview.show()
                yield True
    yield False

def load_data(logfile):
    loader = add_data(logfile)
    load = True
    while load:
        load = loader.next()
        while gtk.events_pending(): gtk.main_iteration()
```